# How to use with_tags when post feed by IOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to post a feed and attach the friend by "with_tags". But no matter I use NSArray or NSDictionary, it always report such error 
`[NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683ee50`  or NSDictionary length.
My code is as below

```
    for(id<FBGraphUser> user in fbFriendPickerController.selection){
            NSDictionary *userDic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:user.id,@"id",user.name,@"name", nil];
            [data setObject:userDic forKey:@"data"];
        }
NSDictionary *param = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test",@"message", data,@"with_tags",nil];
```

Hope someone can help on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to post a feed and attach the friend by "with_tags".

That’s not a valid parameter when *making* a post – it’s field of the post object, when you *read* it from the API.

To *make* a post with tags, you have to use the `tags` parameter – as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: many thanks..but it seems not work. could you please provide some sample code?